# My current GPS Position under Nutiteq is not properly updated

Tags: layer, android-location, map-projections, nutiteq

as basis for my `GPS functionality` I've taken [HelloMap3D](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/blob/master/HelloMap3D/src/com/nutiteq/hellomap/HelloMap3DActivity.java) Example of `Nutiteq` (Thx Jaak) and I adapted to show my `current GPS position` light different of this example, so, no growing yelow circles but a fix blue translucent circle with a `center point` as my current Position and works fine except the update. It should erase the past position if `location` is changed, so that
this update happens as in the example in the method `onLocationChanged`
 [image]

This is the code in my Main Activity

```
protected void initGps(final MyLocationCircle locationCircle) {
    final Projection proj = mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection();

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

             locationCircle.setLocation(proj, location);
             locationCircle.setVisible(true);

        }

         // Another Methods...
     }
}
```

I have adapted `MyLocationCircle` `Class` like this

```
public void update() {

    //Draw center with a drawable
    Bitmap bitmapPosition = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_home);
    PointStyle pointStyle = PointStyle.builder().setBitmap(bitmapPosition).setColor(Color.BLUE).build();

    // Create/update Point
    if ( point == null ) {          
        point = new Point(circlePos, null, pointStyle, null);
        layer.add(point);
    } else { // We just have to change the Position to actual Position
        point.setMapPos(circlePos);
    }

    point.setVisible(visible);


    // Build closed circle
    circleVerts.clear();
    for (float tsj = 0; tsj <= 360; tsj += 360 / NR_OF_CIRCLE_VERTS) {
        MapPos mapPos = new MapPos(circleScale * Math.cos(tsj * Const.DEG_TO_RAD) + circlePos.x, circleScale * Math.sin(tsj * Const.DEG_TO_RAD) + circlePos.y);
        circleVerts.add(mapPos);
    }

    // Create/update line
    if (circle == null) {           
        LineStyle    lineStyle    = LineStyle.builder().setWidth(0.05f).setColor(Color.BLUE).build();
        PolygonStyle polygonStyle = PolygonStyle.builder().setColor(Color.BLUE & 0x80FFFFFF).setLineStyle(lineStyle).build();//0xE0FFFF
        circle = new Polygon(circleVerts, null, polygonStyle, circle_data);

        layer.add(circle);
    } else {
        circle.setVertexList(circleVerts);
    }
    circle.setVisible(visible);
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public void setLocation(Projection proj, Location location) {
    circlePos       = proj.fromWgs84(location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    projectionScale = (float) proj.getBounds().getWidth();
    circleRadius    = location.getAccuracy();

    // Here is the most important modification 
    update();
}
```

So, each time our Position changes is called `onLocationChanged(Location location)` Method and there will be called `locationCircle.setLocation(location)` and last there, it will be called `update` called.

The questions are, **What am I making wrong?** and **How can I solve it?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create and add new circle with every update. You should reuse single one, just update vertexes with setVertexList(). In particular this line should be outside onLocationChanged cycle, somewhere in initGPS perhaps:

```
circle = new Polygon(circleVerts, null, polygonStyle, circle_data);
```

Comment: I already do it with `setVertexList`. Furthermore that `circle_data` was intended in order to distinguish between my own Position and other Geometry Elements but I couldn't show them any more. I'll considere to do outside and say you how it is. Thx

Comment: Jaak, I have assigned like this `circleScale = circleRadius;` (So, NO animation) and I added again `update(zoom)` into the `Thread` in `initGPS(...)` and it works as desired. Thx